# How to prevent VSCode scan installed applications?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode shows the following message every time I start it:

> You have Docker installed on your system. Do you want to install the recommended extensions for it?

The message appears even if Docker is not running at the time when I start VSCode. So I think VSCode scanned the file system to look for what applications I have installed.

Is there any way to opt out from this? This feels like an invasion of my privacy, I do not want Microsoft know what apps I installed. Turning off telemetry does not help, the message still appears.

Comment: This message come from [electron-sandbox/extensionTipsService.ts#L254](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ac74e9d093436886b0fbcf955a5917234853926b/src/vs/platform/extensionManagement/electron-sandbox/extensionTipsService.ts#L254)

Comment: I doubt that your computer's file system is being scanned. It's much more likely that VS Code or an extension checks to see if specific registry entries exist, and if they're specific to another app, it's not an invasion of privacy. If I know in advance that a specific registry entry means a product is installed, and I check to see if that registry entry exists, there's nothing invasive, any more than driving down your street and looking at a building to see if the address is in the 800 block because I'm looking for an address there.